# What are the differences between setting up Firebase via Terminal and Github package link in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I don’t understand where the differences are between setting up Firebase via Terminal and Github-Package link. Are there even differences or is the result the same?

Comment: It is more about the way you like, otherwise it works same.

Answer (score 0):

Both CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager are supported options to add Firebase to your project. Which one you choose depends on your preferences.

For example, if you're working on a project that's using CocoaPods to manage dependencies, you can use CocoaPods to install Firebase as well.

That being said, installing via Swift Package Manager is the preferred way of adding Firebase to your project (see our [blog post here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/firebase-swift-package-manager.html)), and if you start a new project, you should use SPM.